# How to escape ".\file_name" in Hadoop to rename it to "file_name" , I tried few similar examples nothing helped

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file 
   /user/nts/.\file_name in HDFS 
 I want to rename this file to

/user/nts/file_name

hdfs dfs -ls  will list this file

I tried few options what I found in SO

```
hdfs fs -mv '/user/oracle/\.\file_name' hdfs fs -mv '/user/oracle/file_name'
```

Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3. This will escape the dot but the back slash is not

How do I know dot(.) is escaped is because I tied this

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /user/oracle/\.\file_name

rm: `/user/oracle/.file_name': No such file or directory
```

Expected result is file renamed to '/user/oracle/file_name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below command i have tested it

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/oracle/\.\\\file_name /user/oracle/file_name

hadoop fs -ls /
Found 9 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2019-10-23 07:18 /.\b
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup     113183 2019-10-18 05:53 /a.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         74 2019-10-18 07:18 /a.txt
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:15 /benchmarks
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase    supergroup          0 2019-10-21 22:52 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - solr     solr                0 2017-10-23 09:18 /solr
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2019-10-11 04:38 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:17 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:17 /var


hadoop fs -mv "/.\\\b" "/b"

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup     113183 2019-10-18 05:53 /a.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         74 2019-10-18 07:18 /a.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2019-10-23 07:18 /b
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:15 /benchmarks
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase    supergroup          0 2019-10-21 22:52 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - solr     solr                0 2017-10-23 09:18 /solr
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2019-10-11 04:38 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:17 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-10-23 09:17 /var
```